# Squid TCP_DENIED/403 4037 GET http://detectportal.firefox.com/success.txt - HIER_NONE/- text/html

Tags: squid

I've just installed Squid 3.5.27 on Ubuntu Server 18.04

```
user@ubuntu:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
user@ubuntu:~$ 


user@ubuntu:~$ dpkg -l | grep squid
ii  squid                                 3.5.27-1ubuntu1                    amd64        Full featured Web Proxy cache (HTTP proxy)
ii  squid-common                          3.5.27-1ubuntu1                    all          Full featured Web Proxy cache (HTTP proxy) - common files
ii  squid-langpack                        20170901-1                         all          Localized error pages for Squid
user@ubuntu:~$ 


user@ubuntu:~$ squid -v
Squid Cache: Version 3.5.27
Service Name: squid
Ubuntu linux
configure options:  '--build=x86_64-linux-gnu' '--prefix=/usr' '--includedir=${prefix}/include' '--mandir=${prefix}/share/man' '--infodir=${prefix}/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--localstatedir=/var' '--libexecdir=${prefix}/lib/squid3' '--srcdir=.' '--disable-maintainer-mode' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--disable-silent-rules' 'BUILDCXXFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/squid3-28YJxG/squid3-3.5.27=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wno-error=deprecated -Wno-error=format-truncation -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed' '--datadir=/usr/share/squid' '--sysconfdir=/etc/squid' '--libexecdir=/usr/lib/squid' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--enable-inline' '--disable-arch-native' '--enable-async-io=8' '--enable-storeio=ufs,aufs,diskd,rock' '--enable-removal-policies=lru,heap' '--enable-delay-pools' '--enable-cache-digests' '--enable-icap-client' '--enable-follow-x-forwarded-for' '--enable-auth-basic=DB,fake,getpwnam,LDAP,NCSA,NIS,PAM,POP3,RADIUS,SASL,SMB' '--enable-auth-digest=file,LDAP' '--enable-auth-negotiate=kerberos,wrapper' '--enable-auth-ntlm=fake,smb_lm' '--enable-external-acl-helpers=file_userip,kerberos_ldap_group,LDAP_group,session,SQL_session,time_quota,unix_group,wbinfo_group' '--enable-url-rewrite-helpers=fake' '--enable-eui' '--enable-esi' '--enable-icmp' '--enable-zph-qos' '--enable-ecap' '--disable-translation' '--with-swapdir=/var/spool/squid' '--with-logdir=/var/log/squid' '--with-pidfile=/var/run/squid.pid' '--with-filedescriptors=65536' '--with-large-files' '--with-default-user=proxy' '--enable-build-info=Ubuntu linux' '--enable-linux-netfilter' 'build_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/squid3-28YJxG/squid3-3.5.27=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed' 'CPPFLAGS=-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' 'CXXFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/squid3-28YJxG/squid3-3.5.27=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wno-error=deprecated -Wno-error=format-truncation'
user@ubuntu:~$
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. This is the `/var/log/squid/access.log`

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo tail -F /var/log/squid/access.log
1530545854.655      1 192.168.0.254 TCP_DENIED/403 4037 GET http://detectportal.firefox.com/success.txt - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1530545857.667      1 192.168.0.254 TCP_DENIED/403 4037 GET http://detectportal.firefox.com/success.txt - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1530545860.673      0 192.168.0.254 TCP_DENIED/403 4037 GET http://detectportal.firefox.com/success.txt - HIER_NONE/- text/html
```

This is `/etc/squid/squid.conf` config

```
user@ubuntu:~$ egrep -nv '^#|^$' /etc/squid/squid.conf  
980:acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/24
982:acl SSL_ports port 443
983:acl Safe_ports port 80              # http
984:acl Safe_ports port 21              # ftp
985:acl Safe_ports port 443             # https
986:acl Safe_ports port 70              # gopher
987:acl Safe_ports port 210             # wais
988:acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535      # unregistered ports
989:acl Safe_ports port 280             # http-mgmt
990:acl Safe_ports port 488             # gss-http
991:acl Safe_ports port 591             # filemaker
992:acl Safe_ports port 777             # multiling http
993:acl CONNECT method CONNECT
1170:http_access deny !Safe_ports
1173:http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
1176:http_access allow localhost manager
1177:http_access deny manager
1192:http_access allow localhost
1195:http_access deny all
1613:http_port 3128
4256:coredump_dir /var/spool/squid
4887:refresh_pattern ^ftp:              1440    20%     10080
4888:refresh_pattern ^gopher:   1440    0%      1440
4889:refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0        0%      0
4890:refresh_pattern (Release|Packages(.gz)*)$      0       20%     2880
4893:refresh_pattern .          0       20%     4320
user@ubuntu:~$
```

What caused the issue? Was it ACL?

How to fix it?

Answer (score 18):

line 1195  - http_access deny all

That's a catch-all rule that is going to block traffic that hasn't been specifically allowed in the config.  Which, if this is your whole config, is nothing.  Looks like you've got a stock config that will require some allow rules.  Alternatively, modify the http_access deny all and change the deny to allow

If you intend to have authentication setup, you can do something like this:

```
### enforce authentication
http_access deny !auth    # deny anyone that isn't authenticated
http_access allow auth    # allow authenticated users
http_access deny all      # final catch-all that should never actually be met.
```

If you haven't setup authentication yet, then you just need this:

```
http_access allow all
```